# Golang using Null*s in tests

Tags: go

I have some Go tests, and I am trying to use Null*s correctly, but go test is giving errors and I am not sure what is wrong.

Here is the error message:

```
go test ./...
utils/db.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
?       mobifit [no test files]
# mobifit/app/entities
app/entities/user_test.go:34: cannot use dateOfBirth (type func() time.Time) as type time.Time in assignment
app/entities/user_test.go:58: User.Gender undefined (type User has no method Gender)
app/entities/user_test.go:59: User.DateOfBirth undefined (type User has no method DateOfBirth)
app/entities/user_test.go:60: User.Height undefined (type User has no method Height)
app/entities/user_test.go:61: User.CurrentWeight undefined (type User has no method CurrentWeight)
app/entities/user_test.go:65: User.Email undefined (type User has no method Email)
app/entities/user_test.go:66: User.HashedPassword undefined (type User has no method HashedPassword)
app/entities/user_test.go:67: User.FirstName undefined (type User has no method FirstName)
app/entities/user_test.go:68: User.LastName undefined (type User has no method LastName)
app/entities/user_test.go:69: User.CreatedAt undefined (type User has no method CreatedAt)
app/entities/user_test.go:69: too many errors
FAIL    mobifit/app/entities [build failed]
?       mobifit/app/handlers    [no test files]
```

Here are the tests:

```
package entities

import (
    // "database/sql"
    // "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

var (
    email          = "leebrooks0@gmail.com"
    hashedPassword = "password"
    firstName      = "Lee"
    lastName       = "Brooks"
    gender         = Male
    dateOfBirth    = time.Now
    height         = 1.85
    currentWeight  = 101.3
)

func privacyConcernedUser() *User {
    user := new(User)
    user.Email.String = email
    user.HashedPassword.String = hashedPassword
    user.FirstName.String = firstName
    user.LastName.String = lastName
    return user
}

func normalUser() *User {
    user := privacyConcernedUser()
    user.Gender.String = gender
    user.DateOfBirth.Time = dateOfBirth
    user.Height.Float64 = height
    user.CurrentWeight.Float64 = currentWeight
    return user
}

func TestSignUpPrivacyConcernedUser(t *testing.T) {
    user := privacyConcernedUser()
    user.SignUp()

    checkMandatoryValues(t, user)

    assert.Nil(t, user.Gender.String)
    assert.Nil(t, user.DateOfBirth.Time)
    assert.Nil(t, user.Height.Float64)
    assert.Nil(t, user.CurrentWeight.Float64)
}

func TestSignUpNormalUser(t *testing.T) {
    user := normalUser()
    user.SignUp()

    checkMandatoryValues(t, user)

    assert.Equal(t, User.Gender.String, gender)
    assert.Equal(t, User.DateOfBirth.Time, dateOfBirth)
    assert.Equal(t, User.Height.Float64, height)
    assert.Equal(t, User.CurrentWeight.Float64, currentWeight)
}

func checkMandatoryValues(t *testing.T, user *User) {
    assert.Equal(t, User.Email.String, email)
    assert.Equal(t, User.HashedPassword.String, hashedPassword)
    assert.Equal(t, User.FirstName.String, firstName)
    assert.Equal(t, User.LastName.String, lastName)
    assert.NotNil(t, User.CreatedAt.Time) // TODO: Should rather check for not empty
}
```

---

UPDATE: Where is the User type?

```
type User struct {
    Id             sql.NullInt64
    Email          sql.NullString
    HashedPassword sql.NullString
    RoleId         sql.NullInt64
    FirstName      sql.NullString
    LastName       sql.NullString
    Gender         sql.NullString
    DateOfBirth    mysql.NullTime
    Height         sql.NullFloat64
    CurrentWeight  sql.NullFloat64
    CreatedAt      mysql.NullTime
    ConfirmedAt    mysql.NullTime
    LastActivityAt mysql.NullTime
    DeletedAt      mysql.NullTime
}

func (u *User) SignUp() {

}
```

Comment: Can you show the `User` type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this error:

```
app/entities/user_test.go:34: cannot use dateOfBirth (type func() time.Time) as type time.Time in assignment
```

You seem to be trying to assign the function `time.Now` to a `time.Time` field.  Presumably you want to call the function?

For these errors:

```
app/entities/user_test.go:58: User.Gender undefined (type User has no method Gender)
app/entities/user_test.go:59: User.DateOfBirth undefined (type User has no method DateOfBirth)
...
```

It looks like you're trying to access fields on the type `User`, when you really want to be checking the variable `user` (note the case difference).

Lastly, if you are creating sample data with `sql.Null*` fields and want it to resemble real data, you should probably set the `Valid` field to `true` so that you don't trip up code that is actually checking for `NULL` values.